# How to display each state name in d3 india map using GeoJSON

Tags: d3.js, geojson

In my project, I am trying to display India map using d3 and GeoJSON. It works properly, but I am finding difficulties to display each state name on top of the respective state. How to find the centroid of each state.
Please help me to find out, Thanks in advance...,
In the below image, it is displaying at top left corner.

[image]
Index.html

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.state {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #a9a9a9;
    stroke-width: 1;
}

.state:hover {
    fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background: lightsteelblue;
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#tooltip h4 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#tooltip {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 4px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
}

#tooltip table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#tooltip tr td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#tooltip tr td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 50px;
}

#tooltip tr td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="tooltip"></div>
    <!-- div to hold tooltip. -->
    <div style="height: 600px;" id="statesvg"></div>
    <!-- svg to hold the map. -->
    <!-- <script src="indiaState.js"></script> -->
    <!-- creates india State. -->
    <script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function tooltipHtml(n, id, d) { /* function to create html content string in tooltip div. */
        return "<h4>" + id + "</h4>" +
            "<h4>" + n + "</h4>";
    }

    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
    var sampleData = {}; /* Sample random data. */
    ["AP", "AR", "AS", "BR", "CT", "DL", "GA", "GJ", "HR", "HP", "JK", "JH", "KA", "KL", "MP", "MH", "MN", "ML", "MZ", "NL", "OR", "PB", "RJ", "SK", "TN", "TR", "UP", "UT", "WB"]
    .forEach(function(d) {
        var low = Math.round(100 * Math.random());
        sampleData[d] = { color: getRandomColor()};
    });

    /* draw states on id #statesvg */
    //iStates.draw("#statesvg", sampleData, tooltipHtml);

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "600px");

    d3.json("county.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json)
        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .scale(1)
            .translate([0, 0]);

        var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

        function mouseOver(d) {

            d3.select("#tooltip").transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);
            d3.select("#tooltip").html(tooltipHtml(d.n, d.id, sampleData[d.id]))
                .style("left", (d3.event.layerX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.layerY) + "px");
        }

        function mouseOut() {

            d3.select("#tooltip").transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);
        }

        function Click(d) {
            delete d.d
            console.log(d)
        }

        var svg = d3.select("#statesvg")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("height", "100%")
            .append("g");


        svg.selectAll(".state")
            .data(json)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "state")
            .attr("d", function(d) {

                return d.d;
            })
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return sampleData[d.id].color;
            })
            .on("mousemove", mouseOver).on("mouseout", mouseOut).on("click", Click);

        svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(json)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return path.centroid(d.d)[0];
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return path.centroid(d.d)[1];
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.id;
            });

    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried using below code, but its giving both cordinates as NaN, how to solve this...
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .scale(1)
            .translate([0, 0]);

```
    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to county.json?

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/l36bq

Comment: Please check it.

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/john-guerra/43c7656821069d00dcbc  https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/c9cf86eba753ba8650fb466e37d538d2

Comment: Sir that is using topojson, I am not using that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your json is returning the actual path `d` element and not topojson, I'd just use `getBBox` on the path directly.  I also simplified your selections to group the path and the text:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.17" data-semver="3.5.17" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
    <style>
.state {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #a9a9a9;
    stroke-width: 1;
}

.state:hover {
    fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background: lightsteelblue;
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#tooltip h4 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#tooltip {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 4px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
}

#tooltip table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#tooltip tr td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#tooltip tr td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 50px;
}

#tooltip tr td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="tooltip"></div>
    <!-- div to hold tooltip. -->
    <div style="height: 600px;" id="statesvg"></div>
    <!-- svg to hold the map. -->
    <!-- <script src="indiaState.js"></script> -->
    <!-- creates india State. -->
    <!--<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function tooltipHtml(n, id, d) { /* function to create html content string in tooltip div. */
        return "<h4>" + id + "</h4>" +
            "<h4>" + n + "</h4>";
    }

    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
    var sampleData = {}; /* Sample random data. */
    ["AP", "AR", "AS", "BR", "CT", "DL", "GA", "GJ", "HR", "HP", "JK", "JH", "KA", "KL", "MP", "MH", "MN", "ML", "MZ", "NL", "OR", "PB", "RJ", "SK", "TN", "TR", "UP", "UT", "WB"]
    .forEach(function(d) {
        var low = Math.round(100 * Math.random());
        sampleData[d] = { color: getRandomColor()};
    });

    /* draw states on id #statesvg */
    //iStates.draw("#statesvg", sampleData, tooltipHtml);

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "600px");

    d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/l36bq", function(json) {
        //console.log(json)
        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .scale(1)
            .translate([0, 0]);

        var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

        function mouseOver(d) {

            d3.select("#tooltip").transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);
            d3.select("#tooltip").html(tooltipHtml(d.n, d.id, sampleData[d.id]))
                .style("left", (d3.event.layerX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.layerY) + "px");
        }

        function mouseOut() {

            d3.select("#tooltip").transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);
        }

        function Click(d) {
            delete d.d
            console.log(d)
        }

        var svg = d3.select("#statesvg")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("height", "100%")
            .append("g");


        var eS = svg.selectAll(".state")
            .data(json)
            .enter()
            .append("g");
            
        eS.append("path")
            .attr("class", "state")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                return d.d;
            })
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return sampleData[d.id].color;
            })
            .on("mousemove", mouseOver).on("mouseout", mouseOut).on("click", Click)
            
        eS.append("text")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                var bbox = this.previousSibling.getBBox();
                return "translate(" + (bbox.x + bbox.width/2) + "," + (bbox.y + bbox.height/2) + ")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.id;
            });
    });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You probably want `this.previousSibling`, not `this.parentNode`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, `parentNode` would be the `g`, it'll have the same bbox as the `previousSibling` path.

Comment: Well, for me right now (Safari/OS X) all the `bbox.x` are `0`, while changing to the path's box gives the correct `x` position. Chrome works with both `g` and `path` reference, though.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, you mean people still use browsers other then Chrome? :)

Comment: Good one! Well, I'm a Chrome user, but I had to change to Safari because, in the OS X, Chrome drains the battery quite fast... I miss Chrome a lot, but I have to say that I'm enjoying the Safari experience. Also, I'm realising that Chrome is way, way more complacent to errors and typos... I've seen countless questions asking *"hey, this works on Chrome but not on FF, it may be a FF bug"*, but in reality it's a Chrome bug!

Comment: Back to the issue, I have an hypothesis for the behaviour in Safari: the moment you append the texts in the groups they are positioned at `0,0`, and only after that they are translated. That's why calling `getBBox()` on the groups is returning `x = 0` and `y = 0` in Safari. If I set the box *before* appending the texts I get the correct x and y positions.

Comment: @Mark, Thank you, sir, its working. Now how can I Super Impose this D3 paths  on top of google map, Please help

Comment: @Chandrashekhar please don't ask different questions in the comment section, comment section is just for clarification. Post this as a *new* question. Also, I'm seeing that you **never** accepted an answer here at Stack Overflow. That's not a nice behaviour to people trying to help you. To accept an answer, click on the green tick mark at the top-left corner of the answer, just below the upvote and downvote arrows.